# Wordpress Cron Job to invoke javascript function to submit webform

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, cron

I am a Wordpress intermediate developer and a javascript/jquery newbie.  I was recently asked to see if I could create a crowd-sourced webform that multiple employees could add to over the course of the day (production notes), then have the form auto-submit at 5pm every day, which would send the results to all staff.  If there are no notes added by employees, then the form should NOT auto-submit.

Tried breaking the project into it's components:

1. crowd-sourced form
2. function to check for empty fields and auto-submit form
3. Wordpress cron job to run auto-submit function daily at 5pm

The form is powered by a wordpress plugin formidable pro forms, which I use for all webforms for all customers and it's awesome. In it, I have a production notes form that has the ability to save "drafts" for a logged-in user.  The idea is that I would give all staff that need to access the form the same user so they could all add to and save drafts of the form.

The form lives on a page with a custom page template.  I have used the following code for the javascript submit-button click:

```
<script type="application/javascript">

function send_production_notes($) {
    if( $('.production-date-field input').val() == '' ) {
        return;
    } else {
        $('#production-submit').click();
    }
};

</script>
```

Where the script checks the date field to see if it's empty, and if not clicks the submit button.  The idea is that the user will always add the date into the date field if they have notes to share - and they would be trained that way.

Then, I worked on scheduling the Cron Job:

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'ag_send_production_notes_scheduler');

function ag_send_production_notes_scheduler() {
if (! wp_next_scheduled ( 'ag_send_production_notes' )) {
    //Schedule the event, then to repeat daily using the hook 'ag_send_production_notes'
    wp_schedule_event( '1485540300', 'daily', 'ag_send_production_notes' );
}
}

//Hook our function , ag_production_notes(), into the action ag_send_production_notes
add_action( 'ag_send_production_notes', 'ag_production_notes' );
function ag_production_notes(){

if( is_page('production-notes') ) {
echo '<script type="application/javascript">send_production_notes();</script>';
}
}
```

Disregard the details of the `wp_schedule_event`, I was trying several different things so the UNIX timestamp is wrong. I do know the cron job works, because during testing I added a quick php email to the function, and that triggered and sent as expected.

I also know that the javascript function works, I've tested it on the page by wrapping the function in a `jQuery(document).ready()` handler - when the date field was empty, it did nothing.  But if I added the date field then saved a draft (which refreshed the page) it submitted like it should. But I can't have it that way because I need the function to run without someone actually loading the page.

I figure I either have something fundamentally wrong in my code, or am missing some basic concept. I also wasn't sure about the php `is_page` condition, but I found while researching that I needed it to only run the javascript on the relevant page.

In the end, I need the cron job to be able to trigger the javascript submit function daily at 5pm.  I don't know if it's even possible, or if there is a better way for a javascript/jQuery newb like me.  This is also the first time I've messed with Wordpress cron jobs too, but I know that they only get fired when someone visits the site - not an issue for us.

I don't know if the full function needs to be in my functions.php file, or on the production-notes page itself.

I also checked the formidable forms actions from their documentation, and didn't see any action that submitted a form or converted a draft to an entry.  Thank you for your time and constructive help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach here seems very prone to mishap (imagine if someone backspaces someone else's draft [accidently or not]!), and I would propose a slight change to how you are going about the problem.

Had I been tasked with this, my approach would be to have the workers enter their notes, and submit the form.  In the backend I would store the "create datetime" in a field in the database, and this would create tagged entries.  Maybe the plugin does this already? maybe it needs to be updated?

At this point your 5:00PM cron job gathers all the submissions for the day, compiles them, and then sends to compilation to the appropriate email distribution list.

You can determine whether to keep the data, or discard it for the day.  My personal recommendation would be to keep it.  You will always have it to refer to later, and could even write some reporting tools to show how many submissions, by which users (since you could allow each employee to login to a specific user which is more Sarbanes-Oxley compliant, etc.

You can never have too much data, so have them submit everything, while they can, put set the compilation and forwarding to the time when it should be.

---

Edit 1: Create a Specific time of Day call.

You'll want to use a set of functions for date calculation, and SetInterval to execute a script at a given time.

The Code below performs these actions:

1. Set the Date/Time we are checking for (In your case 5:00PM in 24 hour format)
2. If we are past the time, move the check 24 hours ahead to prevent execution
3. If we are at the write time call our function to perform our task
4. Our function to perform our task, submits the form on the page by it's ID handle in the DOM.

   var now = new Date();

   var millis_until_cutoff = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 17, 0, 0, 0) - now;

   if (millis_until_cutoff < 0) 
   {
       //IT'S PAST OUR TIME OF DAY, HOLD OFF TIL TOMORROW
       millis_until_cutoff += 86400000;
   } //END IF MILLIS_UNTIL_CUTOFF

   //EXECUTE OUR FUNCTION AT THE TIME SPECIFIED
   setTimeout(submit_production_form(), millis_until_cutoff);

   function submit_production_form()
   {
       $('#production_form_id').submit();
   }//END FUNCTION SUBMIT_PRODUCTION_FORM

This should handle what you are attempting to accomplish.  Your plugin will need to insert this into the  of the page you are executing the form on, and make sure you change the id (#) of the form in the function.  Also, remember there are some issues with this approach, having multiple windows on the site open to this page will cause multiple submissions, and multiple users who open this page will not be able to see each others edits.

Comment: I appreciate the different perspective! I will explore this alternative, but I would like to also see if my current approach could work.  I suppose I could pull daily entries from a particular form using database queries and a foreach to display them, but then getting them into another email - not sure.  I'm not super worried about mistakes, but you have a point. Saving the data for reference or reporting is not necessary in our situation, but good idea! Do you have any suggestions on making my current approach work?  Thank you again for the feedback!

Comment: Hello, I added an edit to my answer, unfortunately, the Javascript will not apply the "code formatting" for display in the webpage here, but you can access a properly formatted javascript here:  http://pastebin.com/NjBMhwff

Comment: Wow, this is amazing - thank you for taking the time!  So to understand this correctly: I can either use a plugin to insert this javascript onto my production form page, or just add it to the page template in a <script> tag, correct?

Comment: And this would require the production form page to be open on someone's machine for the javascript to be triggered correct?  Since the timing and scheduling is done via javascript, would a wordpress Cron job then be redundant?  THANK YOU again! Whether or not I go this route, this deserves to be the answer.

Comment: Hello, You are correct on all accounts.  This must be inserted into a page, and the Page must be actively viewed by Someone's computer for the Javascript/Jquery to execute.  Thank you for marking the answer!  Goodluck on your project!